# discordpy - Get the Community rules and Discord Updates Channel

Tags: python, discord.py

i use discordpy and i would like to know if theres a property or a method that defines the rules and moderator updates channel in a community server.

I tried finding it in the docs without success and searching online but didnt find anything. i even asked chat gpt (which was a big mistake)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@bot.tree.command(name="channels")
async def channels(interaction:discord.Interaction):
    moderator_only = interaction.guild.public_updates_channel
    rules = interaction.guild.rules_channel
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"Rules channel is: {rules.mention}, Moderator only channel is: {moderator_only.mention}")
```